# Admin server error XDMP-AS when creating new role

Tags: marklogic

I created a role with a name LDAPGroup and assigned an ldap group. After clicking OK button, I got this error.

```
500: internal server error

XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) get-element($col, "sec:role", "sec:role-name",
  $role-name, "SEC-ROLEDNE") 
-- Invalid coercion: $role = sec:role-name("LDAPGroup")
```

Now I can't open my Role page in admin interface. Can someone give me a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please note which version of ML you're running. Also, did you create the role via the Admin UI or through XQY, REST, etc.?

Comment: @wst: i am using 7.0-1 version . I created a role via Admin UI and not by xqueries. I can able to see roles, delete the roles in Qconsole using Sec functions.

Comment: this is the error. 500: Internal Server Error
XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) get-element($col, "sec:role", "sec:role-name", $role-name, "SEC-ROLEDNE") -- Invalid coercion: (fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/roles/4708676013995502179")/sec:role, fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/roles/4720526555240172153")/sec:role) as element()?
In /MarkLogic/security.xqy on line 3591
In get-element("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security", "sec:role", "sec:role-name", sec:role-name("LDAPGroup"), "SEC-ROLEDNE")
$col = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"
$elem = "sec:role"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the second error message it looks like you somehow created two roles with the same name. Names are supposed to be unique, hence the problem. That could have happened if you double-clicked on the form submit when you first created the role. Or possibly you found a server bug.

From your comments about it sounds like you were able to delete the extra role(s) using XQuery and the `sec:remove-role` function. However if the admin UI is still behaving oddly or if you can reproduce the problem, you should report it to MarkLogic support: http://www.marklogic.com/services/support/

Comment: thanks for your reply. I checked roles by checking user. there are two roles with same name - "LDAPGoup". I think i have double-clicked while saving. I used sec:remove-role() to remove other roles. If i remove "LDAPGroup" using sec:remove-role() , I get error. Is there is any way to remove duplicate roles?

Comment: That second error gave you both URIs: `"marklogic.com/xdmp/roles/4708676013995502179", "marklogic.com/xdmp/roles/4720526555240172153"`. Open qconsole, select the Security database, and `xdmp:document-delete` one or both of the URIs. If you like you can also examine either or both of them using `doc` and the URI. Note that updating the Security database directly is a bit dangerous and not really supported, but that is what I would do.

Comment: I deleted both roles using xdmp:document-delete and restarted the server. Now I can able to see all the roles. thanks.  I have some doubts in LDAP authentication. have you done any External authentication via LDAP?